# Does SQL Server's sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities require objects to be bracketed?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run SQL Server's `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` stored procedure to see dependencies on tables and sprocs. I ran `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` for a specific table, `myTable1`, which I know has dependencies in a specific stored procedure, `mySproc2`. However, `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` is returning nothing.

I noticed that in the stored procedure that should be returned with `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities`, it doesn't have the `myTable` in brackets. Basically, it's a simple query that looks like `SELECT * FROM myTable1` and not `SELECT * FROM [myTable1]`.

Would that cause `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` to not return `mySproc2`?

Answer (score 0):

The way you reference the table in the SP shouldn't matter.

But, when you should pass the table name to dm_sql_referencing_entities as two-part name, including the schema. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM  sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.Products', 'OBJECT')
```

You should also be aware that if the reference is from different database on the same instance (for example `SELECT * FROM Sample.dbo.Produts` you won't see that entry in the result set.

Hope it helps.